# Таблица с checkbox для удаления множественных записей DJANGO

Tags: django, checkbox, table, delete

Есть табличка

```
<tbody>
   {% if client_list %}
    <form action="" method="post">
       {% for emp in client_list %}
           <tr>
               <td><input type="checkbox" name="clients" value="{{ emp.pk }}"></td>
               <td>{{ emp.pk }}</td>
               <td><a href="{{ emp.get_absolute_url }}">{{ emp.name }}</a> <span class="badge bg-primary rounded-pill">{{ emp.cnt }}</span></td>
           </tr>
       {% endfor %}
    </form>
   {% else %}
      Список заказчиков пуст!
   {% endif %}
 </tbody>
```

и во views.py пытаюсь удалить несколько выбранных с помощью checkbox записей.

```
def ClientDel(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    client = request.POST.getlist('clients')
    print(client)
    Client.objects.filter(pk__in=client).delete()
return redirect('client_list')
```

Вообщем не работает схема, получается что в переменной "client" ничего нет. Подскажите почему туда ничего не попадает?
Посмотрел в консоли почему то идёт метод GET а должен вроде как POST

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что форма не сабмитилась на сервер. Кнопку встроил не в форме.